# Pivot/Transpose rows into column and convert NULLs into 0's

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, ssms, transpose

I have some data that looks like this:

```
    Table1
    Number        TYPE         Acct         Total
    ------        ---          ---          ----
    1X2           GGG          111          100
    1X2           GGG          222          200
```

What I'm trying to do is PIVOT this data so that it looks like this:

```
   Number         Type         111          222
   -----          ---          ---          ---
   1X2            GGG          100          200
```

Here's how I pivot:

```
   Select * from Table1
                 PIVOT (MAX(Total)
                    FOR ACCT in ([111],[222],[333])
```

Now this works very well for Acct 111 and 222, but for 333 the Total = NULL. Thing is here, that I might sometimes have all three ACCTs, as in 111, 222, and 333. Other times as shown in the above example one of them might be missing.

Anywho, when I do my pivot the data looks like this:

```
       Number         Type         111          222        333
       -----          ---          ---          ---        ---
       1X2            GGG          100          200        NULL <-- I'm trying to set this to 0
```

As you can see, the Value for 333 is NULL - `IS there anyway I can set this value to 0?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options.  The first will use `coalesce()`  to eliminate the null values.  The second will create a a unique set of intersections via a `CROSS JOIN` and a `UNION ALL`  (brute force)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Number] varchar(50),[TYPE] varchar(50),[Acct] varchar(50),[Total] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1X2','GGG',111,100)
,('1X2','GGG',222,200)

Select Number
      ,Type
      ,[111]  = coalesce( [111] ,0)
      ,[222]  = coalesce( [222] ,0)
      ,[333]  = coalesce( [333] ,0)
 From @YourTable
 PIVOT (MAX(Total)
 FOR ACCT in ([111],[222],[333])) pvt
```

---

**Second Option:**

You may notice I supplied the `Accts` in the last `CROSS JOIN` because `333` was not in the scope of the sample data.   If it will exist, you could use the `Select Distinct Acct` like we used in Cross Apply 1 and 2

```
Select *
 From ( Select * from @YourTable
        Union All
        Select Number,Type,Acct,0
         From  ( Select distinct Number  from @YourTable ) A
         Cross Join (Select distinct Type from @YourTable) B
         Cross Join (
                        Select * from  (values ('111' )
                                              ,('222' )
                                              ,('333' )
                                       )v(Acct)
                    ) C
      ) src
 PIVOT (MAX(Total)
 FOR ACCT in ([111],[222],[333])) pvt
```

**Both Results would be**

[image]